# Add Italian holidays into fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use FullCalendar in my application and its working.

Now I need to change the color of Italian holidays into red. I did it for weekends but:

1. I don't know how to add holidays in calendar.
2. How can i change their color.

This is my code :

```
<script>
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next',
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        lang: 'it',
        height: 600,
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            // Changing BG color
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
            //Create modal here
            $('#myModal').modal();
            // Show Date in SPAN
            $('#spnDate').html(date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            // Put Date value in a variable 
            $('#date').attr('value', date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

        },
        editable: true,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you don't need to put holidays in Italy into planner. It's no point, they won't be prepared for you.

Comment: Ok , Whats the solution ? How can i specify holidays ?

Answer (score 8):

You should use another [`eventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) that provides the holidays. These events can have a property like `holiday`, that specify that the event is indeed a holiday.

Based on this `holiday`, you can change the background color of the day with [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

You will have to add the following code to `var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({`:

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: 'fullcalendar/holidays' // url to get holiday events
    }
    // any other sources...
],
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    // lets test if the event has a property called holiday. 
    // If so and it matches '1', change the background of the correct day
    if (event.holiday == '1') {
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']')
                        .css('background-color', '#FAA732');
    }
},
```

Your JSON object should look like this:

> [{"title":"Christmas","start":"2014-12-25","holiday":"1"},{"title":"Another holiday","start":"2014-10-14","holiday":"1"}]