# jQuery fullCalendar set background color for cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I want to set background-color for cell with date 2014-10-22. I find a solution:

```
         date = new Date(y,m,d);
        date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        $('.fc-day[data-date="'+ date +'"]').css('background-color', 'black');
```

but it does not work. Have some ideas?

Comment: Did you see your date alerted for alert($('.fc-day[data-date="'+ date +'"]').text())?

Comment: Nothing is displayed.
code is processed in the method:
viewDisplay: function(view){

}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/artemzakholodilo/CYnJY/200/

on jsfiddle it works fine, but on my local version does not work

Comment: for month view everything working fine, but i need same for day view and week view

Answer (score 2):

`CSS` solution helped me fix this:

**For *Today* date:-**

```
.fc-today {
        background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight {
        background-color: #fff !important;
        background-image: none;
 }
```

**For *Other* days**:

```
.fc-day {
        background-color: green;
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',    
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
         date = new Date();
         date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
         $('.fc-day[data-date="'+ date +'"]').addClass('cellBg');
    }
});
```

see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/201/)

Comment: need same for week view and day view

Comment: change `defaultView: 'month',` to `defaultView: 'basicWeek',`. Do you see the colour working for the WEEK view in your local version?

Comment: got it, and how do this for agendaDay and agendaWeek

Comment: do you need to colour the current date? If yes you can do it easily without the use of `dayRender'.

Comment: i need color date from database, business logic is holiday like 2015-01-07

Comment: I can not see an error here to fix it. You may try wrapping `$('.fc-day[data-date="'+ date +'"]').addClass('cellBg');` with an if statement. `if ($('.fc-day[data-date="'+ date +'"]')) {`

Answer (score 1):

Fergoso: Thanks for your Fiddle. It helped me a lot. I wanted to color the Saturdays, Sundays, and some specific holidays, so, I just updated the Fiddle to do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/203

This are the only things I changed there:

```
//Month is zero-based, so, 9 is october
var holiday_date = new Date(2014,9,20);
var date_as_locale = date.toLocaleDateString();
if (date_as_locale == holiday_date.toLocaleDateString()) {
    enter code here`cell.css("background-color", "red");
}
holiday_date = new Date(2014,9,27);
if (date_as_locale == holiday_date.toLocaleDateString()) {
    enter code here`cell.css("background-color", "red");
}
var day_of_the_week = date.getDay();
if ((day_of_the_week == 0) || (day_of_the_week == 6)){
    cell.css("background-color", "red");
}
```

I only have there two holidays: 20th and 27th of October, 2014. I now there is a better way of doing this, but for now it can be used for demonstration purposes. I will improve it later in order to:
1) The holidays must be independent of the year, ie: the 1st of January must be selected for all years and not just in 2014.
2) The holidays should come from a database, something like the answer from milz here:
[Add Italian holidays into fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361913/add-italian-holidays-into-fullcalendar)

PS: This should be a comment to Fergoso's solution, but since I don't have enough reputation, I can't post it as a comment.

Best regards
Josef

Comment: Something else here: I used: the toLocaleDateString function because: 1) The returned dates from fullCalendar gaves also the time value an not just the date, so, it is not possible to compare the two dates. 2) The time zone of the Fiddle is different than my time zone, so, I need to convert both dates to my local format.

Comment: I just figured out that that code won't work with FullCalendar v2.1.1. The original fiddle is referencing the javascript for 1.6.1. The new version won't work with date object, it uses moment-objects, so, the lines: date.toLocaleDateString(); and date.getDay(); must be replace for their equivalents for the moment library.

Answer (score 0):

@user3058157 wanted to highlight holidays on the agenda views. Unfortunately, according to the docs of FullCalendar 2.1.1 the dayRender callback only works with the month and the basic views. I tried with the agenda views, but no luck.

Some people even talked about hacking the source and insert your own function/trigger. I really don't like this approach because it possible won't work with later versions, so, what I did was to use an eventSource which uses a json feed and set the color and TextColor event properties like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //Add your configuration properties here
    //...
    eventSources: [
    {
        url: 'get_events.php',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
});
```

Then you just have to create the get_event.php file. Mine looks like this (please note that this is a proof of concept, the original data should actually come from a database, I know it isn't efficient, and you even can get only the events you want according to the start and end date and not just create all of them each time you call the php page):

```
    $events = array();
    //Holidays (I included Saturdays and Sundays as well)
    $events[] = array(
        //You can add an id if you want. This is useful if you
        //want to delete the event afterwards
        "id" => 1,
        //Make sure to use utf8_encode if you have special chars
        "title" => utf8_encode("New year"),
        //background and text color for holidays
        "color" => "#C0C0C0",
        "textColor" => "#000000",
        //I only added this fields in order to be able to
        //compare my dates with the ones given by FullCalendar.
        //With a database you won't need this, ie: in mysql you
        //only need to pass the start and end date strings
        "start_date_time" => new DateTime('2014-01-01 00:00:00'),
        "end_date_time" => new DateTime('2014-01-01 23:59:59'),
        //Make sure to do this if you aren't using the allDay Slot
        "allDay" => False,
        //This is a flag I included to differentiate this event
        //from the user events. I'm dynamically deleting events
        //when the user clicks on them, but this excludes holidays
        "holiday" => True
    );
    //Add some more here
    //...

    //Now your own events
    $events[] = array(
        "id" => 30,
        "title" => utf8_encode("Team meeting"),
        "start_date_time" => new DateTime('2014-01-08 10:00:00'),
        "end_date_time" => new DateTime('2014-01-08 10:30:00'),
    );

    //The following is only to simulate a search based
    //on the start and end dates (It is inefficient, I know, but it's
    //a proof of concept as I said) 
    $events_for_web = array();
    foreach ($events as $event)
    {
        if (($start <= $event["start_date_time"]) && ($event["end_date_time"] <= $end))
        {
            //start_date_time and end_date_time must be converted to a string
            //because this is the format supported by FullCalendar
            $event["start"] = $event["start_date_time"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $event["end"] = $event["end_date_time"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $events_for_web[] = $event;
        }
    }

    //Now just output everything as json, which is what
    //FullCalendar expects:
    echo json_encode($events_for_web);
?>
```

I hope that this is useful to you.

Best regards
Josef