# FullCalendar JS - Get the DATE when I click on the grid inside an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to get the date, when I click on the ***grid inside an event***.

I have tried the callback functions.

- dayClick: Not clickable inside events.
- eventClick: No date arguments

Extra information 
I have created an AJAX crud for *Event* and an *EventException* which goes inside the event.
Let's say we have a event 20th-30th December 20XX.
I want to use the exception 25th December 20XX for Christmas Day.

Comment: Can show us your code snippet?

Comment: In eventClick you have access to the start and end date/times of the event. Is not not enough? Why do you need to know? If the user clicked on the event, they're interested in that event. Even if the event spans multiple days, why do you care exactly which of the days they clicked on? They registered an interest in the event, not the date. You can't do what you're requesting, so I'm interested in the reason you want it, in case there's a better way to achieve the same ultimate outcome.

Comment: Lets say I wanted to create an exception within the event range.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have an event _range_, you have a single event. If you want to create a gap in the middle of the event, you have to turn it into 2 separate events. That's the only way. And you can't determine simply by the user's click where that gap should go. You'd have to put in some extra UI to ask the user exactly where to create the gap. The calendar has no way to know which day within the event you clicked on, (I suspect partly because of the way it's rendered using multiple layered tables). This kind of thing has been asked before on SO.

Comment: @del nothing to do with code snippet

Comment: ADyson .. What do you think about the performance. If I were to get break down an event into days. Render individual days in Calendar. This needs to be done for multiple events. I don't think its practical

Comment: How many are we talking about? The calendar can only display one month max at one time, so there must be some realistic limit on the number of events likely to appear? Anyway you don't really have any other option except to break it down. Not necessarily into individual days, but you certainly have to separate it according to where you need your break to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Like you said, "separate it according to where you need your break to appear". I want to be able to to select and get the value of that break point on the calendar.

Comment: for that you have to ask the user the question. There is no other way to do it. The calendar does not possess that information. Perhaps you could re-write the source code so it does, but I think it would be very difficult. If it was easy, it would be a feature already.

Answer (score 1):

In html, note that we are going to add another method handler call eventClickEx to the current fullcalender.

```
  eventClickEx: function(jsEvent,ev,view,cellDate){
    alert(cellDate);
  }
```

In fullcalendar.js. Also in fullcalendar. In here we are calling getCellDate which is not available in view right now.

```
 EventPointing.prototype.handleClick = function (seg, ev) {
        var hit = this.view.queryHit(getEvX(ev),getEvY(ev));
        var cellDate =  this.view.getCellDateEx(hit.row,hit.col);
        var res = this.component.publiclyTrigger('eventClickEx', {
            context: seg.el[0],
            args: [seg.footprint.getEventLegacy(), ev, this.view,cellDate]
        });
        if (res === false) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    };
```

Since it's not available, we will be using the BasicView class which has access to the dayGrid object.

```
BasicView.prototype.getCellDateEx = function (row,col){
  return this.dayGrid.getCellDate(row,col);
};
```

There you go, when you click the event, you will get the underlying date from cellDate .

Comment: Thank you for willingness to help. But seems too tedious to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Since each Fullcalendar day is stacked behind the event occurring in that date, you cannot get the clicked date. You have three possible workaround:

1. when you click the event you can show a modal with datepicker and select the "exception date/range"... then you set the break of your event in the backend.
2. To set the "exception date/range" you can directly click on the date (not the event) and set it as "invalid" or whatever.
3. Create a context menu with item "Add exception here" which would fire only when clicking on date (not event)

Anyway, if you have a 10 days event, and set an exception in the middle.. The end date should be moved forward by one day.. 
Youc an eventually set some days as "holiday", check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361913/add-italian-holidays-into-fullcalendar?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score -1):

I hope the documentation of FullCalendar JS will help you with it..
refer to the article here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

  }
});
```